# On uniformly randomly choosing a pure quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, randomness

If I have a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A$, how can one uniformly randomly choose a pure quantum state in this space?

I believe the answer is to take the state $\vert 0\rangle$ and apply a random unitary to it. This random unitary is chosen according to a measure called the Haar measure. I do not have a measure theory background so I'm struggling to understand this and the mathematical discussions about the Haar measure are hard to follow.

Is there a physicist's guide to understanding how to pick a random quantum state from some Hilbert space such that every state is equiprobable?

Comment: What do you mean by "a physicists guide"?  Do you want to have a code snippet how to choose a Haar random state/unitary? Do you want to understand *why* such a procedure works? Do you want something more abstract? Do you want an explicitly paramterized form?

Comment: The physics guide is a guide on Haar measure.  You have the answer but you're line is to say "I can't understand it".  I'm not sure how one is to answer besides learning what's a Haar measure or else if you don't even bother about such background a simple Google search produces plenty of algorithm to generate Haar-random matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but this may help.

A Hilbert space is a complete normed vector space. The norm gives vectors a length and an angle between pairs of vectors. From this, you can get volumes and areas. You want to choose states whose norm is $1$. That is, you want to pick vectors uniformly from the unit sphere. Dividing the sphere into small patches of area $\epsilon$, you want the same probability of being in any patch.

Googling "choosing points uniformly on n-dimensional spheres" turns up a number of solutions for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Wolfram has [this one](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html). Here is something on [Geometry of high-dimensional space](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf)

But if you have an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, it gets trickier. You need a Haar measure. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure),

> The Haar measure assigns an "invariant volume" to subsets of locally
>   compact topological groups, consequently defining an integral for
>   functions on those groups.

This doesn't sound very helpful. But a Hilbert space is a locally compact topological group. It means a Haar measure allows you to define integration over subsets of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

But I don't know if it is possible possible to choose a uniform distribution over an infinite dimensional hypersphere. From the Wikipedia article on the [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), you can see the surface area of the unit sphere goes to 0 as the dimension increases. If all patches on the sphere have area $0$, it is hard to choose patches of comparable size.

Part of the trickiness is that you can form the set of all ordered infinity-tuples $(x_0, x_1, ...)$. But not all of these represent points in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. A Hilbert space has a norm, which means that all vectors have a finite length. The usual norm is $\sqrt{{x_0}^2 + {x_1}^2 + ...}$ This means  $(1/2, 1/4, ...)$ is a vector in the space, but $(1, 1, ...)$ is not.

Suppose you pick some patch around $(1,0,0,...)$, and another very similar patch around $(0,1,0,...)$, and so on. You now have an infinite number of patches that all must have equal probability. The probability of each is infinitesimal.